# Shared GPS position from smartphone to my personal website

Tags: android, html, api, dictionary, gps

I would like to share my GPS position from android phone to my personal website and put a marker on google map. Can I use the API V3 ? I don't understand how is the ID or trust between smart phone and map... google API is the best way ? My website is build with HTML5.

Thanks

Comment: nothing except tried to understand how to send informations from android

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve your current position, you can use the following [link](https://github.com/andreamontanari/android/blob/master/GPSTracker.java) to understand how GPS works in Android.

Once you retrieve your position, you have many ways to "pass" this information to your website, I suggest you one:
Save the position on a free Database and request it from your website when you load the page

Answer (score 0):

http://herverenault.fr/self-hosted-gps-tracker/demo/i-am-here

I will try this one. Source code can be posted directly on my web server in PHP format.